# Strange behaviour with Differences

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some problems with the built-in function `Differences`. I do not understand how its behaviour comes about under the following circumstances:

```
vec = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
vec2 = ConstantArray[1, 10];

Differences[#, 1, 0]^2 & /@ {vec, vec2}
```

gives me

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

as an output. What is the reason for the 1 in the last entry of the second list? Shouldn't it be 0 as well?

Comment: Win10 V11.2 returns only `0s`.

Comment: Good to know. I use Linux V10.0.1. So it is supposed to be a bug I guess?

Comment: Win 7 MMA 11.2 also returns only `0s`

Comment: Version 11.0.1 on macos 10.13.3 also returns `zeroes` only. Have you tried to restart the kernel before running the code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? The zero in the third slot of `Differences` indicates how many steps apart in the array elements should be so not entirely sure 0 makes sense here in the first place

Comment: Yes, I restarted the kernel several time, same result. Of course, the result is trivial here, though I was surprised when I tried different approaches for instance for an MSD computation that the results were different. However, all the other results obtained by `Differences[]` seem to be reliable so far.

Comment: Can you specify your exact Mathematica version and operating system?

Comment: Fedora Linux 64-bit, `$VersionNumber=10.`